# Display remaining work from tasks on PBI in kanban

Tags: azure, devops, scrum, scrumboard

I've got a backlog setup where we track product backlog items through the kanban board and add estimated times on tasks. The default view of the kanban does not display the time estimated on the tasks. Is there any way to configure the kanban board to show that value?

The field on Tasks that is populated with time is called "Remaining work".
The field on the PBI does not count that value.

In the Sprint Backlog task view it looks like this:

[image: Sprint Backlog view]

On the Kanban board the PBI is displayed like this:

[image: Kanban view]

I wish to see the 8h remaining work that I can see on the sprint backlog on the kanban board as well. Is this possible?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want to use the sum of hours estimated on Tasks to show as Remaining Work on the Boards view. Currently you get that when you're in the Sprint Tasks view. But that value isn't stored on the product backlog item.

It would also work if you could get the Tasks estimated hours to show next to it if you expand the view in Boards. Like this:

[image]

**EDIT2:** Adding more fields to be shown does not produce this value. As the value shown in Sprint Backlog task view is an aggregate of the Remaining work on tasks and not stored on the product backlog item.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way (I know) to display that sum on the Kanban board. I don't know any extensions doing it either, but I haven't checked for them to be honest.

We created a styling rule for work items that haven't changed state for a few days to make them visible on the board (to i.e. ask about it on standups), that's the only workaround I can suggest.

Comment: I figured as much. Our workaround was to reconfigure the burndown to go from the remaining work field of product backlog item instead of tasks.